# How to get most Retweeted Tweet using Linq To Twitter

Tags: linq-to-twitter

Is it possible to retrieve the tweet that is most retweeted? I searched out for the solution but did not any find any clue, Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean of all the tweets on Twitter? There isn't a Twitter API call for that. However, if you had access to the Firehose stream, you could watch all tweets and calculate it. That said, it would be much more work than a quick query.

If you wanted the most retweeted tweet of a user, you could query their tweets and then do a LINQ to Objects query for RetweetCount.